# Installing ubuntu broke my windows install

Tags: installation, windows, partitioning, permissions, dual-boot

So i went out and brought an HP DV6 laptop.

The laptop came pre-installed with windows 7 Home premium.

The laptop had several partitions.

A `system` partition which appears to be a boot loader only.
A `Windows` partition with, as you can guess the windows install.
A `Recovery` partition, which is used to run recovery if windows fails.
A `HPTools` partition, which im not sure what that is.

So, When I got the laptop I shrunk the `windows` partition as much as I could, and then created an empty partition using the unused space (using the windows partition manager).

I then installed ubuntu 11.04 using the live CD into the new partition.

ubuntu works fine, and in the boot loader I have
`ubuntu`, `ubuntu (recovery)`, `memory test`, `memory test (again)`, `Windows 7 (Loader)`, `Windows 7 (Loader)`.

If I choose the first `Windows 7 (Loader)` Windows starts to load, The boot animation gets to a certian point, then it gets the BSOD.

If I choose the second `Windows 7 (Loader)` I get told that windows failed to load as it does not have permission to access the drive.

I then get the option to Run windows repair.

But when I choose this option I simply get the grub loader.

How can I fix this?

Gparted shows 
[image: View from Gparted]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that you should be able to mount (at least in read-only mode) the windows partition, you should be able to grab all the data you need of it, wipe the machine then re-install the OS's its a crude method, but certainly the easiest.

At any rate, have a clean install of windows without any of the pre-installed HP software will run better.